# Is it possible to have a tkinter window transparent but the widgets on it solid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make an overlay for my screen with text but whenever I open a transparent tkinter screen with:

```
app.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.1)
```

the labels and buttons are almost fully transparent too, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, tkinter doesn't support alpha ranges for individual widgets or colors.

But you can use `-transparentcolor` instead. This lets you choose a single color to apply full transparency to.

**Note:** `-alpha` and `-transparentcolor` are both toplevel attributes and, as such, will affect all child widgets added to the window.

The code below illustrates some effects of `-transparentcolor`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root['bg'] = 'grey'
root.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'grey')

lbl = tk.Label(text='Hello World!', font='Helvetica 36 bold', bg='green', fg='grey')
btn = tk.Button(text='Button', font='Helvetica 36', bg='grey', fg='blue')
canvas = tk.Canvas(bg='grey')

lbl.pack()
canvas.pack()
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: " But that works the same " This isn't true, transparentcolor is significantly different to alpha. Please do a review on your answer.

Comment: @Atlas435 Poor wording on my part. I only meant that they are both toplevel attributes. Edited for clarity. Let me know if anything else sticks out or feel free to edit yourself. Or, by all means, slap me around some more if I'm completely wrong. I don't wanna put wrong answers out there or mislead anyone.